# USB token - *.dll detection

Tags: java, cryptography, smartcard, signature

I implemented application in Java which enables to **sign document** (pdf/xml) using hardware token. To use this solution user has to configure token - he has to specify proper *.dll driver file.

Is it possible to automagically detect proper *.dll file? I saw a few programms which do it automatically or user should only choose hardware from the list. I mean solution on Windows.

Comment: What do you mean by "detect"? You can always write Java code to search the whole file system for a specific DLL file; to then load it; as shown in the answer you got. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I mean find is by select USB token from USB devices list and get proper dll without search whole file system. If token is installed correctly it should be possible to get which dll use.

Answer (score 0):

If you know which DLL file you want to load, you can use the `System.loadLibrary()` function to force loading of a particular DLL file.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary(java.lang.String)

Comment: I don't know. I wonder how to detect which dll is proper without user action.